# Compiling with gcc c99, not with ideone c99. Integer Overflow

Tags: c, c99

```
int rng(int min, int max){
    int result = min + ( ( (max - (min - 1) ) * rand() ) / (RAND_MAX + 1) );
    return result;
}
```

This won't compile with ideone using c99 mode, but does so when I'm using gcc on CodeBlocks while on `-std=c99`. I figured using long int would do the trick, but apparently not so. I use ideone when I'm trying some stuff in school since they just have VC++ and I'm doing C C99. I wouldn't want to *not* use this function when I need it, and so here I am asking for what is wrong.

Comment: Please post actual compile errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, on my compiler this produces `warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]`.

The problem is caused by `RAND_MAX + 1`. `RAND_MAX` often happens to be the same as `INT_MAX`. Adding `1` to `INT_MAX` of course yields undefined behavior (except the compiler catches at compile time and replaces the code with something else).

If you want to see in action why it's bad, do this:

```
scanf("%d", &dummy); /* So the compiler won't catch it. */
dummy += INT_MAX;

gcc -ftrapv -Wall -Wextra # ftrapv is the key point
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out in ideone.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { printf("%x\n", RAND_MAX); return 0; }
```

You'll notice that it prints `7fffffff`, which is probably also `MAX_INT`.  What happens when you compute `MAX_INT + 1`?  Computing `MAX_INT + 1` is wrong, whether or not you get an error.

There are many ways to write a uniform random number generator given a uniform RNG with a different range, but doing so correctly is a bit tricky.

This should work whenever `max - min <= RAND_MAX` and `max > min`...

```
int rng(int min, int max)
{
    int range = max - min + 1;
    int factor = ((unsigned) RAND_MAX + 1) / range;
    int x;
    do {
        x = rand() / factor;
    } while (x >= range);
    return x + min;
}
```

This should be both uniform and give relatively high quality numbers (using `%` is known to cause severe quality problems with some PRNGs and certain ranges).

Comment: What happens when `min == max`... (and I think you are missing a `+ min` from your return value).

Comment: @caf: Fixed.  Note that precondition states `max > min`.  I just want to illustrate the core, not write a complete, tested piece of production code.

Answer (score 1):

Without the actual error text, it's hard to tell, but the presence of "Integer Overflow" in the title points to ..., well, an integer overflow :-)

The most likely culprit there is your `RAND_MAX +1` bit, if `RAND_MAX` is actually the same as `INT_MAX`.

If you're willing to forego *perfect* distribution of your random numbers <sup>(a)</sup>, you could opt for something like:

```
int rng (int minVal, int maxVal) {
    int result = min + (rand() % (maxVal + 1 - minVal));
    return result;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The "damage" done by this is usually minimal but it *does* slightly skew the distribution away from the highest value. If that's important, there are other ways but, for most people other than statisticians, the damage is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This can indeed produce integer overflow, if `(max - min + 1) * RAND_MAX > INT_MAX`.  You have a couple of options on how to avoid that:

- cast the intermediate values to a type that can store them without overflow, such as `uint64_t` or `double`, or
- use the modulus operator `%` instead, like this:

```c
int rng ( int min, int max ) {
    return min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
}
```

Note that using `%` has a few drawbacks: if `max - min + 1` is not a power of two, it will slightly bias the results towards the low end of the range (because it will not divide `RAND_MAX+1` evenly); and if it *is* a power of two, it may reduce the period and quality of the random number stream (because the low bits of a [LCRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) are less random than the high bits).

There are ways to avoid these issues through careful coding.  For an example, see the standard [`Random.nextInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) implementation in Java, which can be quite straightforwardly translated into C:

```c
int rng (int min, int max) {
    int n = max - min + 1;
    int bits, val;

    if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
        return min + (int)((n * (uint64_t)rand()) / ((uint64_t)RAND_MAX + 1));

    do {
        bits = rand();
        val = bits % n;
    } while(bits - val > RAND_MAX - (n-1));

    return min + val;
}
```

(I *think* this translation should work as intended.  It turned out a bit trickier than I though, since the original Java code relies, in effect, on the assumption that `INT_MAX = RAND_MAX = (1<<31)-1`, which might not hold in C.)

Comment: You should put a cast on `RAND_MAX` if you use it that way.